# jQuery can't see context

Tags: jquery

I have HTML page with several frames on it. One of frames(called Main) contains several INPUT's.

When I use this:

```
Main.document.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

It works fine. But then I try do the same in jQuery:

```
$("input",Main)
$("input",Main.document)
$("input",window.Main)
$("input",window.Main.document)
```

All of them returns null. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
`$(Main)` returns null too.

**UPDATE**
jQuery is included inside of Main frame.

at base page I have that row:

```
<script>$=Main.$;</script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery being properly included in the page?

Comment: Does your JS console say anything like "Main is not defined"?

Comment: @mmmshuddup no. Main!=null and $!=null. But $(Main)==null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery cannot return `null` for selectors. It's very likely that you have included the wrong library, such as Mootools. You have to include jQuery at the main window. If `$` is overwritten, you can still use `jQuery` instead of `$` to use jQuery methods.

When you've made sure that you've included jQuery, use `frames.Main` or `frames["main"]`, to have a readable code. `Main` will not point to the frame when you define a variable called Main.

It's recommended to not use the jQuery framework of the main when the frame also included jQuery, because some settings are different per window. Use:

```
frames["main"].$("input"); //Use the jQuery method of the frame.
```

Comment: document.frames["Main"].$("input") is null

Comment: @MeelStorm Add `alert($().jquery)`. If it returns `null`, you haven't included jQuery. Refer to the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: it was a conflict!!! thank you! i just used Main.jQuery.noConflict(); and then use Main.jQuery instead of Main.$

Comment: @MeelStorm `jQuery.noConflict()` isn't needed, since `$` is not a jQuery object any more. `$.noConflict()` is used to revert `$` to the previous object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frame-id').contents().find('input');
});
```

Be sure that your iframe is currently ready.

Comment: $(Main.document) returns null.